# Custom page / message after installation of wordpress plugins

Tags: wordpress

I want to give some tips to the people that install my plugins. So after the installation of the plugin I want them to see an instruccion page, or go directly to the configuration of the plugin.

Any hook after the activation of the plugin where I can redirect to a page ?

I could use some flash message too for the same goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `register_activation_hook` function registers a plugin function to be run when the plugin is activated.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'redirect_to_instruction_page');
function redirect_to_instruction_page(){
    wp_redirect( admin_url( 'admin.php?page=instructions' ) );
    exit;
}
```